# How to update an existing entry in ORC streaming sink?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, orc

When persisting a stream into a file using the Apache ORC file format, is there a way to perform an update to an entry? Instead of appending and effectively having an entry multiple time when updating an entry.

```
incomingStreamDF.writeStream
  .format("orc")
  .option("path", "/mnt/adls/orc")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/adls/orc/check")
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
  .start()
```

It seems that ORC support update, so is there a way to indicate the key of the entry maybe in the writeStream options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** No (up to and including Spark 2.4)

The only output mode that could give you such a feature would be `Update` output mode. Since `orc` format is a `FileFormat` it [must always be used with Append output mode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L286-L293).

---

A solution to the issue could be to use the brand new [DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@foreachBatch(function:(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D,Long)=%3EUnit):org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter%5BT%5D) operator (or the older [DataStreamWriter.foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@foreach(writer:org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter%5BT%5D)) where you process the data however you like (and you could easily update an entry in an ORC file if you know how to do so).

> **foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[T], Long) ⇒ Unit): DataStreamWriter[T]**
>
> Sets the output of the streaming query to be processed using the provided `function`.
>
> This is supported only in the micro-batch execution modes (that is, when the trigger is not continuous).
>
> The provided function will be called in every micro-batch with:
>
> (i) the output rows as a Dataset
>
> (ii) the batch identifier.
>
> The batchId can be used deduplicate and transactionally write the output (that is, the provided Dataset) to external systems.
>
> The output Dataset is guaranteed to exactly same for the same batchId (assuming all operations are deterministic in the query).